# How to make the background image like this site?

Tags: jquery, html, css, width

http://disney.pageonewebsolutions.com/

This website background image perfectly fit to his div.
I was wondering if anyone can help me to create the site like this.

Appreciate any reply.

Comment: HTML questions should not be placed here... see faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background image is applied using the following CSS

`body { background: #fcc900 url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat top center; }`

The `top` and `center` keywords make sure that the background image is always displayed in the top-center of the screen and image itself was probably created with the container `div` in mind, leaving the correct dimensions free for the content.

If you still unsure about how to achieve these effects, view the source and try and apply the techniques you find to your own design.

Answer (score 7):

Just take a look at the CSS for the background:

```
background:url("../images/background.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top #FCC900;
```

The "center" does the trick: it makes the background always stay in the centre.

Answer (score -1):

By using `<center>` on the background image?

Comment: No, that won't work, and even if it did, `<center>` is a deprecated tag.